# Typecasting or initialization, which is better in Swift?

Tags: swift

Since Swift does a strict check for types, sometimes we need to convert between NSString and String, NSArray and [AnyObject], etc. But in fact there are two different ways to do this:

1. Typecasting, such as `str as String`
2. Initialization, such as`String(str)`

Which is more recommended in Swift? Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are talking about casting vs. coercion. It isn't a matter of "recommended". They are completely different things.

- *Casting* is merely a way of redescribing something to the compiler. Your redescription must be true already, or you will crash at runtime.

  For example, you can cast an AnyObject to a String (with `as!`) just in case it *is* a string; you are simply telling the compiler about this, so that you can then send String-related messages to this object. The cast is legal because String is bridged to NSString and an NSString is an AnyObject, so *this* AnyObject might indeed be a String. But if you lie and this is *not* a string, you'll crash later when the app runs and you try to cast to a String something that is not in fact already a String.
- *Coercion* makes a new object entirely. It works only just in case the new type has an *initializer* that accepts the old object.

  For example, you cannot cast between numeric types in Swift. You have to coerce, which is a completely different thing - that is, you must make a new object of a different numeric type, based on the original object. The only way to use an Int8 where a UInt8 is expected is to coerce it: `UInt8(x)`. And this is legal because UInt8 has an Int8 initializer (as you can see in the Swift header):

  ```
  extension UInt8 {
      public init(_ v: Int8)
      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: And see my book. Coercion: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_coercion Casting: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_casting

Comment: Thanks very much! So is it more closer to the language designer's intention to use `as` with regard to bridged types?

Comment: @yzyzsun Yes, because they _are_ bridged so they _are_ the same type. No need to make a new object.